# I want navbar header to be fixed and others to be scrolling?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying keep the header in a fixed position ,I have tried all possible solutions but not able to achieve it.

Here is my link to codepen:https://codepen.io/saisree/pen/WjVjMW

```
<div id="Nav" class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-static" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="https://codepen.io/saisree/full/WjVjMW/">Anand Reddy</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ">
        <li class="active"><a class="0" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="1" href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a  class="2" href="#family" >Meet the family</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blog" class="3 ">Blog</a></li>



                                              <li ><a href="#testimonial" class="4">Testimonials</a></li>
                                                              <li ><a href="#spec" class="5">Specialization</a></li>
                                                   <li ><a class="6" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                                                      </ul> 
          </div>
```

Any kind oh help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add **"navbar-fixed-top"** class to the main nav.

```
<div id="Nav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse  navbar-static" role="navigation">
```

In addition your markup is incorrect and you have missed two closing div tags, so all your content goes into the nav actually...

Here is an updated codepen: [Click](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXYJeG)

Comment: hey thanks! But I'm not able to open your code pen...its getting refreshed continuously!